# Request timedout during delete/create on elasticsearch while snapshot is being taken

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I am using nodejs to connect to elasticsearch and use curator to take hourly snapshots.

When snapshop operation is running, many create/delete requests timed out after waiting for 30s. More serious problem is that during delete even request timedout and client assumed deletion failed but it succeeded, maybe after timed out occurred. This resulted in corruption of data.

I have also noticed that time to take snapshot continuously increasing linearly. After 6 months now it takes 4 minutes, even though it claims that backup is incremental process.

I have used the following command to take the backup

```
/usr/local/bin/curator snapshot --repository mt_es_backup indices --all-indices >> /vol/es/es_backup.log 2>&1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curator is not likely to be the issue here (Disclosure: I'm the author of Elasticsearch Curator).

The count of snapshots in your repository can have an impact on snapshot duration and even cluster performance during snapshots.  Snapshots in Elasticsearch *are* incremental at the file level, but the files in question are called segments.

**Segments**

The most fundamental unit of storage in Elasticsearch is a segment.  As documents enter Elasticsearch to be indexed, they are processed into a buffer.  When that buffer is flushed, its contents become a segment.  Once created, a segment is immutable.  In order to keep Elasticsearch from filling your disk with tiny segments, *and also* to keep it from consuming a ton of resources (inodes, file handles, etc), it [merges segments from time to time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/merge-process.html).  These merge operations are effectively re-indexing the contents of two or more segments into one larger segment.  This happens continuously in indices that are indexing new documents.  (It is nearly  transparent to end users, but [monitoring APIs can show some detail](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_monitoring_individual_nodes.html)).

**Snapshots**

As stated, snapshots capture at the segment level.  This means that increments are not at the document level, but rather *segments that have changed since the last snapshot.*  Let's say a snapshot captured segments *a1*, *a2*, and *a3* into *snapshot1*.  Then a few minutes later, these segments get merged into *b1*.  When the next snapshot is taken, segments *a1*, *a2*, and *a3* no longer exist, but *b1* does, and so the same documents which were in segments *a1*, *a2*, and *a3* exist in both *snapshot1* and in segment *b1* in *snapshot2*.  The reasoning for this seemingly unnecessary duplication of data is that a snapshot *must* be able to restore *exactly* to a point in time, right down to the individual segments.

Incremental also means that all segments to be snapshotted have to be compared to all segments within the repository to ensure no duplication of segments happens.  **This is why the duration of time required to take snapshots increases with the number of snapshots in the repository.**

The increase in disk I/O from segment checking is almost certainly why index and delete operations are timing out during snapshot operations.  This effect will worsen as the number of segments to check increases, as your own request here clearly shows.

**A Potential Solution: Multi-tiered snapshot repositories**.

This approach works well if you have time-series data, like log or metric data.  This approach implies hourly snapshots, but also adds another tier of *daily* snapshots, perhaps in an altogether different repository.  For example, you might only keep hourly snapshots until the daily indices have been optimized to 1 or 2 segments per shard, and then are snapshotted into their own repository.  This would mean hourly snapshots would only need to be kept for 48 - 72 hours.  With this approach you'd have fewer segments to worry about, and restores would become more streamlined, with fewer files/segments to restore.

You *can* still use this approach with non-time-series-data, but it loses some of the benefits of merging segments before taking the next tier of snapshots.  It will still result in fewer segments in the repository between checks, and that's the end goal here, for your cluster's performance.

Comment: Thank you so much for valuable insights!

Answer (score 1):

I did quite some reading on this. I believe the snapshot creation is taking so much time because ElasticSearch needs to analyse the already existing snapshot and then copy only the new data to the snapshot repository. Deleting the older snapshot should help. Also, deleting older snapshot will only removing the segments which are not in use by other snapshots, so there will be no data loss.

This was an open issue on github too: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8958

After looking at our repository, I found that there 2K+ snapshots residing there dating back to 25th Aug 2015. Keeping only snapshots worth a month is more than enough.